# Technical example of modeling a domain with OOD?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design, domain-model, design-principles

Considering favoring composition over inheritance and looking at various design patterns there are multiple approaches to modeling a domain.

Say you have some Entities which are very similar in some respects, yet differ widely when it comes to technical implementations. To try portray the scenario here is the classic car example.

```
(Vehicles)
Car
Truck
Van
```

From a user perspective, they are all pretty much the same (all vehicles). From a **DDD** perspective, car, truck, van all share certain common state (number of tires, engine, ...) and certain behaviors (steering, changing speed, ...). However, they also have various state and behavior that is unique such as the Truck's bed, the van's internal storage, or the cars 5 seats. As time progresses there will be a fair amount of change. Validation would be different for certain things, and similar for others. Change speed, steer, etc. are similar, yet pull trailer is optional and even that differs between e.g. the Van and Truck.

How would you design this to cope with change, yet remain DRY and adhering to the **DDD** mindset? Please explain how you would go about it (pseudo code?) and mention any design patterns or strategies you would try implement to model this (simple, yet dynamic) domain and which OO principles are being applied etc.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the purpose of the model is missing from the picture. DDD is not about modelling reality: it's about discovering the model which is the best fit for the specific purpose. Design patterns will eventually follow.

Comment: :) Excellent, I wanted but can't give you more than 1 up, sorry about that

Comment: btw, I read what DDD is about. Still have no clue what it is. But what you said applies for software design, not just this or that methodology.

Comment: I may expand my words a little.

Comment: No no, your wording is fine. I just don't understand the things they write to define and describe DDD.

Comment: I may expand my words a little. After 10 years the Blue Book now looks misleading to me. The elegance of the design that it apparently advocates is in fact just a necessary condition of a *continuous learning* path that leads to *frequent rewriting*. One can't continuously evolving a codebase efficiently if the design is missing. However not all codebases _need_ to be continuously evolved. This happens only in very complex areas (we need to change code as long as we learn) or in areas with highly evolutionary forces (i.e. business or market pressure).

Comment: Unfortunately, from many sources (including the Blue Book itself) one can get the impression that DDD is just a way to do elegant Domain Models. In the past, I used to be guilty of this sin too.

Comment: It's ... so vague. I'm curious to see the modeling of those couple example Entities, I'm assuming everyone can imagine a specific purpose, I'd like to see example technical implementation. DDD is just to give context (Entities contain state and behavior). This reminds me of Head first design patterns grasshopper "discussions". :)

Comment: Sorry for that, but when you say: "I'm assuming everyone can imagine a specific purpose" is like saying "I want a one-size-fits-all model" while DDD is exactly the opposite. Wrote a post on a similar topic, years ago: http://ziobrando.blogspot.com/2010/06/about-entities-aggregates-and-data.html not the answer you seek, but an example of how a simple answer is not in the cards.

Comment: Yup. The first thing I thought of is, how are these vehicles going to be used?  Understanding the WHY these objects even need to be modeled is the first step.

Comment: @ZioBrando I would replace "discovering the model" with "discovering the behaviour", as it's the behaviour we seek to emulate, rather than the physical properties.

Comment: @TomPickles precision vs precision... I meant what I've written. :-) It's not about 'emulating', it's about finding the best model for solving a given user's problem. Behaviour is way more interesting than static data properties, such as cardinality, but it may lead us to mimic reality rather than solving a business problem.